# Error 401 when configuring BCryptPasswordEncoder for Restful Api application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

why when I configure @Bean BCryptPasswordEncoder and use it in the service save user, when I run the application the requests return 401 error, when I turn off the BCryptPasswordEncoder function, everything works normally.
This is code in SecurityConfig

```
@Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
```

This is code when i use BCryptPasswordEncoder for encoder password before save in database

```
@Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    @Override
    public UserDTO save(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User newUser;
        if (userDTO.getId() == null) {
            String passEncoder = passwordEncoder.encode(userDTO.getPassword());
            Role roleUser = roleService.findByName("USER");
            newUser = userConverter.ConverterUserDTOToUser(userDTO);
            newUser.setPassword(passEncoder);
            newUser.getRoles().add(roleUser);
            newUser.setStatus(1);
        } else {
            User oldUser = userRepository.findById(userDTO.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Not fpund user with id " + userDTO.getId()));
            newUser = userConverter.ConverterNewUserDTOToOldUser(userDTO, oldUser);
            newUser.setStatus(oldUser.getStatus());
            newUser.setRoles(oldUser.getRoles());
        }
        newUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
        UserDTO dto = userConverter.ConverterUserToUserDTO(newUser);
        return dto;
}
```

if I comment all the code related to BCrypt in the config and service, everything works normally

Comment: Too little information... I assume you're using Spring Security. How does your Spring Security configuration look like? Did you used debugging for getting the values compared by the PasswordEncoder? Just a guess, but when you're updating an existing user, is it possible to update the user's password too? If yes, do you encode the new password before persiting the entity?

Comment: i'm doing user creation, not login, and i want to add BCryptPasswordEncoder to encrypt password before saving to database, represented by code if (userDTO.getId() == null) { ... } , now I don't know why, but when using BCryptPasswordEncoder, every request returns 401 error, when not used, everything is normal.